# Home button changing from drawer icon to up button on rotation - only when nav drawer is open

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a navigation drawer in my app and for the most part it appears to be working OK.

I have the home button set to be the nav drawer icon(hamburger) and this persists across normal rotations. As can be seen in Image 1 (portrait) and Image 2 (landscape after rotation). 
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

However If i open the nav drawer, then rotate the screen and then close the nav drawer, the home button changes to the up button, as can be seen in image 3. 
[image: Image 3]

I have tried changes things around so that it constantly remains the hamburger icon but have had no luck.

My Code for the **MainActivity** is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
Toolbar toolbar;
private String mDrawerTitle;
private String mTitle;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private static int sNavPosition = 0;
private static final String NAV_POSITION_KEY = "navKey";
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDrawerTitle = getTitle().toString();
    mTitle = getTitle().toString();
    mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_fragment_items);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    setUpToolbar();
    NavDrawerItem[] navDrawerItems = new NavDrawerItem[4];

    navDrawerItems[0] = new NavDrawerItem(getString(R.string.nav_home));
    navDrawerItems[1] = new NavDrawerItem(getString(R.string.nav_aims));
    navDrawerItems[2] = new NavDrawerItem(getString(R.string.nav_arttrail));
    navDrawerItems[3] = new NavDrawerItem(getString(R.string.nav_submission));

    DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item,navDrawerItems);
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_header,null);
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    setUpDrawerToggle();
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(NAV_POSITION_KEY)){
        sNavPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(NAV_POSITION_KEY);
    }
    new DrawerItemClickListener().selectItem(sNavPosition);
}

private void setUpDrawerToggle(){
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}



@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

private void setUpToolbar(){
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}



@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    outState.putInt(NAV_POSITION_KEY,sNavPosition);
}
```

}

I have excluded unnecessary code regarding click listeners for navigation.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Removing `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`and
   `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);` from ur
`setUpDrawerToggle();`method

```
Edit: setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) hides the default back button
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, thanks for the help anyway. Anymore suggestions are welcome

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); is used to hide the default back button.

Comment: I decided to setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) in the onDrawerClose event, and it is now working. Thank you.